# Do we need to import PropTypes and define contextTypes when we change path after a promise is resolved?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In react-router v2 and v3, we could do

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";

class PostsNew extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }

  handleUserSubmit(props) {
    this.props.createPost(props)
      .then(() => {
        // the post has been created successfully
        // now route back to index
        this.context.router.push("/");
      });
  }

  // ...
```

but in react-router v4, if all we need to do is `this.props.history.push()` instead of using `context`:

```
  handleUserSubmit(props) {
    this.props.createPost(props)
      .then(() => {
        // the post has been created successfully
        // now route back to index
        this.props.history.push("/");
      });
  }
```

then can we skip the import of `PropTypes` and the definition of `contextTypes`?  And so changing path will be as simple as `this.props.history.push("/");` if we use react-router v4?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Or you can use the [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component.

Comment: do you mean "Yes, we do still need to use `PropTypes` and `contextTypes`" or "Yes, then we don't need to use `PropTypes` or `contextTypes`"?

Comment: can we skip the import of PropTypes and the definition of contextTypes? Yes.